# document.selection.createRange() does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was trying make a simple ubb editor, but document.selection.createRange() does not work in IE and it just won't get any highlighted text(try to alert the highlighted text yet get nothing). I am still not able to find the reason and solve this.

[You can have a look at this script in action here](http://www.sharingbus.info/public/ubb/ubb.html)

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ubb = document.getElementById('ubb_code');
    var ubba = ubb.getElementsByTagName('a');//ubb buttons
    var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];//editable textarea filed 

    //onclick to insert ubbcode
    ubba[0].onclick = function() {
        tag('[b]','[/b]');
    };

    //function used to insert ubbcode
    function tag(tag1,tag2){
        // code for IE
        if (document.selection){
            textarea.focus();
            var sel = textarea.document.selection.createRange();//It DOES NOT work!
            //alert(sel.text);
            sel.text = tag1 + sel.text + tag2;
        }else{  
        // code for none-IE webbrowsers
            var len = textarea.value.length;
            var start = textarea.selectionStart;
            var end = textarea.selectionEnd;


            var scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = textarea.scrollLeft;


            var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
            //alert(sel);
            var rep = tag1 + sel + tag2;
            textarea.value =  textarea.value.substring(0,start) + rep + textarea.value.substring(end,len);

            textarea.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            textarea.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
        }
}
```

Comment: if you use document.selection.createRange() for IE and want to keep the highlighted text when you trigger some function, use onmousedown instead of onclick, cause onclick will destroy selection in IE!

Answer (score 1):

Update : IE9 supports this functionality
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536394(v=vs.85).aspx

```
if (document.selection.createRange) {       // Internet Explorer
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var selText = range.text;
    var htmltext = range.htmlText;                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE11,selection object is no more supported.
you can use window.getSelection to achieve the same behaviour.
For more info please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)